# Android AlarmManager triggering alarm immediately

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to schedule an alarm 15 min before a certain fixed time. But my alarm is triggered as soon as it is set and not when it should trigger. The time set is not in the past. I verified the alarmTime by converting it to date and it is correct. Also my `BroadcastReceiver` is registered correctly (in `AndroidManifest.xml`).

Any suggestions ?

Here is my code below :

```
setAlarm(long fixedTime){

    final int beforeTime = 15*60; // 15 min before
    final Long alarmTime = (fixedTime - beforeTime)*1000L;
    final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)   context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, getIntent());
}


private PendingIntent getIntent(){

    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 22714, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    return pi;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem and I could not understand exactly what the problem is, your BroadcastReceiver is not invoked, or is the wrong time?

Comment: Why isn't `beforeTime` in milliseconds?

Comment: try final int beforeTime = 15*60*1000; // 15 min before
    final Long alarmTime = (fixedTime - beforeTime);

Comment: @ Andre : Broadcast receiver is invoked immediately when I invoke setAlarm() which is at the wrong time. It should invoke 15 min before fixedTime.

Comment: @JDJ : fixedtime is in seconds so I am converting it to mili seconds after the subtraction

Answer (score 0):

The timezone was the issue. Device was using default timezone which was in the past and hence the alarm was triggered immediately.

Comment: so how to change the timezone? when setting alarm